# How to create JKS keystore file on secure domain for java netty-socketIO

Tags: java, openssl, netty-socketio

I need to create a JKS keystore file on a secure domain (eg: https://example.com).

I am going to use this keystore file in my java netty-socketIO server side.

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.setHostname("example.com");
 config.setPort(3037);
 config.setKeyStorePassword("password");
 InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:/keystore.jks");
 config.setKeyStore(stream);
```

I am not so sure what is the best way to create the jks file and what is needed for this one.

I am using windows vps for this java socket program.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use java's keytool tool.
You should have java installed and the JDK bin folder in your PATH (if not run it from the JDK's bin directory).

```
$ keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -genkey -alias myalias
```

Answer the questions with the values you want to store to your first key (myalias) and the tool will create a keystore including a key with alias myalias.

When done you can list the keys of the keystore with

```
$ keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -list
```

Comment: Hello Loannis. I tried to follow your steps. but I got this error.

`keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mykeystore.jks (Access is denied)`

I am not sure what it means.

Comment: It means that you do not have write access on the Directory you run the keytool from. If you are in Windows 8-10  and you tried to run it from Program Files you might not have write access. Try to open CMD using Admin rights (elevated Command Line).

Comment: Yes it worked for me, by the way, how can I set the domain name(eg: https://example.com) when I create the JKS file.
Or it is needless as long as we are creating it on the secure domain(in my case vps)?

Comment: The domain name should be added under SAN attribute (Subject Alternative Name) of the certificate. You can do: keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -genkey -alias myalias -ext san=dns:example.com